# I want to sort arrays, but I can't?

Tags: php, json, sorting, foreach

I have a JSON file that I created, and I want to sort from the biggest price value.

JSON is like this:

```
[
  {
    "username": "elbugato",
    "sold": 19,
    "qmimi": 38.5
  },
  {
    "username": "Pablo",
    "sold": 12,
    "qmimi": 42
  },
  {
    "username": "Hqstuff",
    "sold": 0,
    "qmimi": "0"
  },
  {
    "username": "matchspamm3rs",
    "sold": 0,
    "qmimi": "0"
  },
  {
    "username": "Pachenko",
    "sold": 1,
    "qmimi": 1.1
  },
```

I want to sort qmimi from the highest value

My php code is this.

```
$sellertop8json = json_decode(get_html('link'));
$i = 1;
sort($sellertop8json->qmimi, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($sellertop8json as $top8){
max($top8);
        if (++$i == 8) break;


    echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$top8->username.'</td>
    <td># '.$top8->sold.'</td>
    <td>$ '.$top8->qmimi.'</td>
    </tr>
    ';


}
```

but they aren't sorting from the biggest value
The results I get :

[image: result]

Look at "Pachenko", he is after a seller that has "0" Earned.

Thank You
Sorry for my bad English

P.S : JSON ISN'T RAW, I copied from some extension I am using on google chrome, so JSON it's not the problem.

Comment: You should be able to find the algorithm to sort arrays on web easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and provide custom function comparing the field of the element:

```
usort($sellertop8json, function($a, $b) {
           return $a->qmimi == $b->qmimi ? 0 :
                   $a->qmimi < $b->qmimi ? 1 : -1;
      }
);
```

The comparison function must return `0` if the elements are equal, less than `0` if the first element is lower and greater than `0` if the second element is higher.

This may be a bit confusing as you're sorting from highest and therefore the swap of the sign in comparison - see the last part of comparison.